# How do I get rid of question marks in the OS X Dock?

Tags: macos

How do I get rid of grey question marks in the Dock of a Mac desktop? I have dragged them off the dock in an attempt to remove them and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to drag them off some distance (and wait for a second or so) until an image of a *cloud* appears next to the mouse pointer. Only then should you drop the icon.

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively, right-click the icon on the Dock, and select *Options » Remove from Dock*.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try left clicking, dragging the icon and holding it until you see a little cloud, and then the item should be deleted. However if this does not work, you can always delete you plist file com.apple.dock.plist; in /Users/YourName/Library/Preferences. Drag that file from the Preferences folder to the Trash, empty your Trash and restart your Mac. If the ? mark is still in the Dock, try dragging it back off.

Comment: **Drag that file from the Preferences folder to the Trash, empty your Trash and restart your Mac. If the ? mark is still in the Dock, try dragging it back off.** You are giving conflicting instructions. Please edit and post again

Answer (score 0):

If *Drag-n-Drop* or *Right click on the icon* → *Options* → *Remove from Dock* didn't work you could just reset your Dock to default using the command below

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock
```

**Note :** *Anything that was added to Dock by you would need to be re-added*